# ERROR Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1, ERROR : Found conflicting resources

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am using latest Titanium Studio version and i have imported an android project which is developed using JavaScript.

I have installed all the Android SDK's.

when i am running the project using android emulator i am facing this issue

```
[INFO] :   Emulator is booted
[INFO] :   SD card not required, skipping mount check
[INFO] :   Emulator ready!
**[ERROR]:   Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1, [ERROR]:   Found conflicting resources**
```

I am not able to trace out what is causing this issue.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are you running default project or any developed code?

Comment: i am using a developed code.

Comment: is it alloy or commonJS or classic project?

Comment: Its a commonJS project!

Comment: ok so are you setting any extra property in tiapp.xml for android manifest?

Comment: this is the only setting i am using in tiapp.xml

    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <manifest>
            <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/>
        </manifest>
    </android>

Answer (score 0):

delete the application from the emulator and re-install it. That usually resolves the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

**I finally found the issue.. i had few images with same name in different folders, when deleted, it got fixed and app is running now. Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is file with **same name but different extension**. You can however have same file name in different folders